# How do I jsonize an array of user defined objects?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, marshalling, stringify

I have a an object PARENT defined like the following

```
function PARENT(name, childs){
   this.name=name;
   var childsArray=New Array();

   childs.forEach(function(child_info) {
          childsArray.push(new CHILD(child_info));
      })
      this.childsArray=childsArray;
}
```

Then there is another object CHILD defined as

```
function CHILD(_child_info) {
  this.name = child_info.name;
  this.age  = child_info.age;

 }
```

Given an array of PARENT objects I would like to get the following json object

```
[
{name:"parent 1 name",
childs : [
           {
             name:"child 1 name",
             age:"child 1 age"  
           },
           {
             name:"child 2 name",
             age:"child 2 age"  
           },
           {
             name:"child 3 name",
             age:"child 3 age"  
           }
         ]
}, ...
{name:"parent n name",
childs : [
           {
             name:"child 1 name",
             age:"child 1 age"  
           },
           {
             name:"child 2 name",
             age:"child 2 age"  
           }
         ]
}
]
```

but when I try to stringify the array of PARENT I get an empty JSON object {}

How can I achieve this?

Comment: JSON doesn't have any way to represent user-defined objects. It's a language-agnostic serialization format.

Comment: But you should still get the objects, you just won't get the prototypes and methods.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. 
I ended up writing a function for the user defined object that build the string and then I parse it ... right now I face another issue as the returned JSON is inside a Promise value object

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call